# How to append a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to simply add a '/' at the end of this string. What is the best way to do this?

```
>> params[:id]
"shirts"
```

I would like to make `params[:id] == "shirts/"` . How do I add a `/` at the end of that string?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simplest:

```
params[:id] = params[:id] + '/'
```

or

```
params[:id] += '/'
```

Moar fancy:

```
params[:id] << '/'
```

Yet another way to do this:

```
params[:id].concat '/'
```

If you really really for some bizzare reason insist on gsub:

```
params[:id].gsub! /$/, '/'
```

Answer (score 4):

"Best" depends largely on your use case but consider the following code:

```
a = 'shirts'
b = a
params = {}
params[:id] = b
params[:id] << '/'
params[:id] #=> "shirts/"
```

As we'd expect, `<<` has added a slash but...

```
a #=> "shirts/"
# a has changed too!
```

So, depending on your level of understanding with these methods, this is a behavior you might not expect. Compare to:

```
params[:id] += '/'
params[:id] #=> "shirts/"
a #=> "shirts"
# a remains the same
```

Basically, some methods create new objects and others modify existing ones. We can test this with the **object_id** method.

```
str1 = 'a'
str2 = str1
str1.object_id #=> 14310680
str2.object_id #=> 14310680
# Both str1 and str2 point to the same object
```

Now

```
str1 << 'b' #=> "ab"
str1.object_id #=> 14310680
str2 #=> "ab"
```

We've successfully modified str1 without creating a new object and since str2 still points to the same object it also gets the "update". Finally, if we use the `+=` method:

```
str1 #=> "ab"
str1 += '' #=> "ab"
str1.object_id #=> 15078280
str2.object_id #=> 14310680
```

Notice that we have added nothing to str1 but it still creates a new object.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
params[:id] + '/' == 'shirts/'
```

No gsub needed :)

Unless you there might be a trailing slash in some cases. Then use:

```
params[:id] = params[:id] + '/' unless params[:id].match(/.*\/$/)
params[:id] == 'shirts/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Shovel operator?

```
params[:id] << "/"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `params[:id] << "/"` should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to build a URL this way, you're probably doing it wrong, but I can't tell you the right way to do it.

If you're trying to build a directory path this way, and there's other bits to the path, use something like `File.join`. [Link to the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M000031)