# Given a string, how to append a carriage return followed by another string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string like so `string1`:

```
Hello World, join my game:
```

I would like to make string1 become:

```
Hello World, join my game:

http://game.com/url
```

How can I append a carriage return with ruby and then a link from another variable?

THanks

Comment: `"#{string1}\n\nhttp://game.com/url"`

Comment: @Michael Perhaps you meant to have a `#` instead of a `%`?

Comment: @Michael pretty sure that's actually `"#{string1}"`, not `"%{string1}"`

Comment: @MrTheWalrus Yeah, typed too fast.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to append a string in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196571/how-to-append-a-string-in-ruby)

Comment: Pretty sure you're asking about new lines, or "line feeds" to use your parlance... "carriage returns" are something else https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It really depends on what you are outputting to.

$STDOUT:

```
puts "Hello\n\n#{myURL}"
```

or

```
puts "Hello"
puts
puts myURL
```

or

```
puts <<EOF
Hello

#{myURL}
EOF
```

If you are outputting this in an `html.erb` or `.rhtml` document:

```
<%= "Hello<br /><br />#{myURL}" %> # or link_to helper
```

If you already have a string like `string1` then you can append to it using either `+=` or `<<`:

```
string1  = "Hello world, join my game:"
myUrl    = "http://example.com"
string1 += "\n\n#{myUrl}"
```

or:

```
string1 = "Hello world, join my game:"
myUrl   = "http://example.com"
string +=<<EOF

#{myUrl}
Here's some other details
EOF
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you have these strings:

```
string1 = 'foo'
string2 = 'bar'
```

Here's three ways to combine them with a newline in between:

String Interpolation:

```
"#{string1}\n#{string2}"
```

'+' Operator:

```
string1 + "\n" + string2
```

Array and .join

```
[string1, "\n", string2].join
```

OR

```
[string1, string2].join("\n")
```

Comment: `[string1, string2].join("\n")` is super clean, especially when you have lots of strings. If some of the strings might be `nil`, you can use `[string1, string2].compact.join("\n")` to get rid of any `nil` values.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no new line constant.  Use escape sequence '\n'.  like:

```
puts "1. Hello\n2. World"
```

Ref: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings

Comment: There is global variable `$/` that represents new line.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using puts statements, a simple way to print on new lines is as follows:

```
puts "Hello, here is the output on line1", "followed by some output on line2"
```

This will return:

```
Hello, here is the output on line1
followed by some output on line2
```

if you run the code in the irb in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

### Output as an Array.

If you're appending multiple times to the same String variable and you want to later output each of these appended Strings in new lines, you might want to consider using an Array to store each String in and then just join them with a new line when displaying/outputting them.

```
output = []

output << "Hello World, join my game:"

output << "http://game.com/url"

output << "Thank You!"
```

Now, if you're in terminal or something, you can just use `puts` on the output Array:

```
puts output
#=> Hello World, join my game:
#=> http://game.com/url
#=> Thank You!
```

If you want to display it in HTML you might want to use the `join()` method:

```
output.join('<br>')
#=> "Hello World, join my game:<br>http://game.com/url<br>Thank You!"
```

You can use whatever you like in the `join()` method, so if you wanted to have two line breaks between each string, you could do this:

```
puts output.join("\n\n")
#=> Hello World, join my game:

#=> http://game.com/url

#=> Thank You!
```